# Flushing notify-osd queue?

Tags: 11.04, notify-osd

I use 11.04, Classic and sometimes the notifications just pile up, e.g. when I open thunderbird, and login to empathy, and start playing my music, all at once. I can see messages popping for 15 minutes or more. The Ubuntu wiki on notify-osd mentions [Flood Prevention](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Flood%20prevention). Why isnt it being applied in this case? This overflow/flood didnt happen in 10.04.

I tried killing and restarting the notify-osd process, but then new notifications dont show up. The Me-menu hangs up, and I have to log out to make it alright.

Is this a bug? How do I flush the queue? Is there any workaround?

EDIT: I was able grab a screenshot. And now, all of a sudden, the messages have stopped popping.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how exactly the "flood protection" works, but 15 minutes of messages sounds like those applications are **seriously abusing** the notification system...

Comment: In a similar context, I have this with XChat highlights ('Alerts') which get directed to notify-osd and in case of some mass-highlighting just keep on piling up.

Comment: Mmm, I get this with Empathy... If I have an over enthusiastic mate talking, I'll be forever seeing notifications.

Answer (score 4):

The Wiki article you pointed to is not a currently implemented spec - it's a suggested guide for developers of features that should be implemented and how they should be implemented.

> This is the design specification for Notify OSD. If you are a software developer looking for advice on making your software compatible with Notify OSD, see NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines.
>   This specification contains some issues not yet resolved. Your feedback is welcome at NotifyOSD/Comments.

This will likely be implemented in the future, for now it's rough going when the queue piles up.